# World War One officer sees visions of punk future

Tags: story-identification, tv

Back in the late 1970s/early 1980s on UK TV I watched some drama or TV movie or a play.

The basic story was a British army officer in World War One was struggling to survive the constant attacks across No Man's Land.

Then he started getting visions of the future he was fighting for, however the glimpses were without sound, he kept gazing in horror at punk rockers in full regalia pogo-ing to various punk bands and muttering astonished and dismayed "Barbarians!" to himself.

I can't remember how it ended but I know he was having a "what's the point of dying for those brutes?" mental crisis

Update!
I've had another memory, he initially found some artifact that was unearthed by a shell in the Flemish mud, I can't visualise exactly what it was but I think it was a small lozenge shape (it was a muddy blob on my TV screen and he was rubbing the dirt off it) after that is when his future visions began

Comment: Ah, yes, the [punks are evil brutes slur](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheQuincyPunk). Rabbit-hole warning: TVTropes.

Comment: Bit of a stretch, could it be Biggles; Adventures Across Time?  WWI (fighter pilot), travels to the 80's (not quite a fit as it is more than just a vision), came out in 1986.

Comment: No not Biggles, I deffo watched this a few years before that, I think that punk was still fairly new then so probably the late 1970s

Comment: @JohnHunt Going to have to watch that again now ...